# R function to cast to wide format

Tags: r, reshape

Possibly a fairly simple question, however I have not been able to solve it so far. My goal is to redesign a data frame in R that has the following format:

| var1 | year | Jan | Feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 2019 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| x2 | 2020 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| x1 | 2020 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| x2 | 2019 | 3 | 1 | 1 |

to wide format: In the way that it results in the following table:

| year | 2020 | 2020 | 2020 | 2019 | 2019 | 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Jan | Feb | March | Jan | Feb | March |
| x1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| x2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 |

I am  highly thankful for any advice or help!!

Comment: All elements in a df column vector have to be the same type.  Jan-2020 as a column name with numeric values would work. Jan, Feb... as row values would not unless you are satisfied with all numeric values maintained as character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be useful:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
new <- df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = year,values_from=Jan:March)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  var1  Jan_2019 Jan_2020 Feb_2019 Feb_2020 March_2019 March_2020
  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>      <int>      <int>
1 x1           1        1        2        2          3          2
2 x2           3        2        1        2          1          3
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("x1", "x2", "x1", "x2"), year = c(2019L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2019L), Jan = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), Feb = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), March = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your super fast response. This works just as expected. Thanks alot!!!!

Comment: @JuliusS Always a pleasure helping dear!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` way would be :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), var1~year, value.var = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'March'))

#   var1 Jan_2019 Jan_2020 Feb_2019 Feb_2020 March_2019 March_2020
#1:   x1        1        1        2        2          3          2
#2:   x2        3        2        1        2          1          3
```